# Vba is not running all the line because of this line

Tags: excel, vba

By mistake I write this line: `newWBK.Sheets(nSheet).Range(coloana & "41").NumberFormat = """0.0"" hours"""`

I am just curious why my code when "meet" this line just think that the subroutine is over. I do not have any errors nothing, the code is just going to another subroutine.

When I write this line correct: `newWBK.Sheets(nSheet).Range(coloana & "41").NumberFormat = "0.0"" hours"""` the code is been executed.

Comment: Your invalid code line throws an runtime error (1004). When you don't see this error, you likely have some `On Error` error handling in your code that suppresses that or jumps to an error handler. Unless you show more of your code, it's impossible to tell, but debugging the code step by step should tell you what is going on.

Comment: I disable the `On Error Resume Next`. But the code is too long. When I put the piece of code (that make to skip the rest of the code) in a new sub, I have the error like you 1004. I have to dig more

Comment: Advice: You should never put `On Error Resume Next` in your code. It's just hiding errors (but the statement of course doesn't work). You can never understand what's going wrong if you tell the VBA runtime not to inform you that something is going wrong

Comment: I have to insert repetitive a text in a several worksheets so I have made the sub like this: `Sub insert_Text(ByRef nSheet As String, coloana As String)` I have no error traps inside of the code because it is just some formulas that needs to be insert + some font formating. So the code is ending when execute `.NumberFormat = """0.0"" hours"""` . When I put the same code but without indirect referance so without this `ByRef nSheet As String, coloana As String` I have error 1004 (from the invalide format of the cell).